# Cannot connect to Windows 7 shares from Ubuntu 9.04!

Tags: windows-7, linux

This has been driving me crazy!!! I updated one of my windows boxes from XP to Windows 7 and now my Ubuntu boxes cannot connect to the shares on that windows box!!!! I have done a lot of research on this and anything I try does not work. any Ideas??

Comment: What errors do you get? Do the shares show up from "smbclient -L //server" for example?

Comment: I tried the command you suggested without a password when it asks for one. With a password I get "session setup failed: SUCCESS - 0" When I do not specify a password I get

Anonymous login successful and it shows info about the computer I am trying to connect to like server name workgroup name , etc. But the most puzzling error message comes next. It says "cli_rpc_pipeopen: cli_nt_create on pipe \srvsvc to machine [ipaddress] .   Error was NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't state what you already tried, it's likely that this is among the attempts you made:

From [Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/75-63-windows-samba-issue):

> Control Panel - Administrative Tools - Local Security Policy
>
> Local Policies - Security Options
>
> Network security: LAN Manager authentication level
>   Send LM & NTLM responses
>
> Minimum session security for NTLM SSP
>   Disable Require 128-bit encryption

or there are a few other things to try in that thread.

Comment: I have done all but disable 128 bit encryption. I will look into that that!

Comment: no such luck. look at the info i gave pjc50 above on this...

Comment: Did you read the thread that I linked to? There are several other things to try.